# Error while checking for the user rights at the selection of a radiobutton and clicking the next button

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5, wix3

I have a scenario in which i check for the user rights (whether a standard user or admin):

i am using something like:

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" 
Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">

<Condition Message="Message text">Privileged</Condition>
<Publish Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1">INSTALLPREFA = "Every"</Publish>
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="MyInstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
```

However it generates as error :

```
C:\myproject\MyInstallPrefa.wxs(25) : error CNDL0005 : The Publish element c ontains an     
unexpected child element 'Condition'.
```

Can't i check for admin rights inside a  in a custom dialog , kindly help!!!.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states: `Condition` element cannot be used inside `Publish` element.
The condition is written as the inner text of [`Publish`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_publish.htm) element.

Comment: So you meant i need to write <Publish Message="">Priileged</Publish>,something lke this.

Comment: @eddie Yes, I do. Look at how `Publish` elements look in the excerpt you posted.

Comment: :Publish element http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_publish.htm does not have a text property

Comment: :can u post the statement here.

Comment: I did not say about text attribute, I talked about element text; element text is what is between the opening tag and the closing tag. From the link you posted: _**Inner Text (xs:string)**: The element value is the optional Condition expression._

Comment: And I said in my reply to your comment, that I mean something like that: `<Publish Message="">Privileged</Publish>`.

Comment: :I used exactly what you wrote <Publish Message="">Privileged</Publish> however compiling it gave me an error as C:\myproject\MyInstallPrefa.wxs(23) : error CNDL0044 : The Publish element's
 Event or Property attribute was not found; one of these is required.How do i get rid of this now?

Comment: Because `Publish` element does not have `Message` attribute, and I didn't say it was the correct statement, I only pointed out where the condition must be written. You have to create a dialog, or use an existing one, to show the error message. Read [WiX tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial) about making UI.

Comment: I have the UI created and i am writing the <Publish > statement under <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13011/discussion-between-alexey-ivanov-and-eddie)